# Decision Tree. Strategy for noise

Tags: artificial-intelligence, data-mining, decision-tree

What are the good strategies to combat noise in decision tree?

In my training data,

I have two records with the same attributes but they give different classification.

1. Female, Luxury, LV, Yes
2. Female, Luxury, LV, No

Based on my reading, it says to return the plurality classification of these two records.

But that will raise a problem when i want to make a prediction because the output of my prediction should be either yes or no.

So, trying to find out what are the strategies I can use in this case to predict.

Thank you.

Comment: Alternatives: 1. Remove such contradictions, 2. Add more properties for making decisions, that is `Female, Luxury, LV` should be complemented with additional disambiguating feature, bringing 2 different selectors - one for `yes`, and one for `no`. 3. Can you afford a fuzzy approach, that is storing probabilities as decisions instead of concrete `yes` or `no`?

Comment: **Pruning** deals with noise in non-class-attributes, and probabilties in the leaves handles ambiguous classes.

Comment: @Stan. It is an assignment so I can't really say how badly the questions are set. Thank you!

Comment: Yet, even in the assignment you can detect a data which should be normally treated as inconsistent, with a decision/advice it to be skipped. At least, this is a real-world approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the class prediction is undecided:

1. The easiest (and common) approach is to **predict the majority class**.
2. **Get some more information**. For example include additional attributes (if available) or get more training samples (if available).
3. **Remove some information**. The intention is to remove as many sources of noise as possible while preserving the predictive information as much as possible. Commonly it's done by removing useless attributes. In the case of tree it can be done by pruning. Eventually you can remove outliers (like wrongly measured samples) but you have to know which sample is the outlier.